# firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider is undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase to authenticate a user. I have setup Firebase like so:

**firebase.js**

```
const firebase = require("firebase-admin")

const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json")

firebase.initializeApp({
  credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://logbook-96180.firebaseio.com/"
})

module.exports = firebase
```

I then import `firebase` in another file to authenticate a user.

**auth.js**

```
const firebase = require("./firebase")

...

const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    null,
    accessToken
  )

firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
```

When I execute the authentication, I receive an error `Cannot read property 'credential' of undefined`, showing that `firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider` is undefined.

Are there any reasons as to why this could be the case? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're using the Node.js client SDK but requiring the Admin SDK. Try using the web setup instructions instead of Admin. https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: @JenPerson I need the Admin SDK since I'm using Firebase database, am I unable to authenticate a user via access token with the Admin SDK?

Comment: Why do you need to use the Admin SDK instead of the Node.js Client SDK? Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish? Are you trying to verify the Id token?